# How to update counts by date in table A with the counts by date returned from join of table B and table C

Tags: t-sql, join, sql-update, multiple-tables

I can do this using a temporary table. **Is it possible to do these two steps in a single update query?**
All possible dates already exist in the TargetTable (no inserts are necessary).
I'm hoping to make this more efficient since it is run often as batches of data periodically pour into table T2.

Table T1: list of individual dates inserted or updated in this batch

Table T2: datetime2(3) field followed by several data fields, may be thousands for any particular date

Goal: update TargetTable: date field followed by int field to hold the total records by date (may have just come in to T2 or may be additional records appended to existing records already in T2)

```
select T1.date as TargetDate, count(*) as CountF1 
    into #Temp
    from T1 inner join T2
    on T1.date = cast(T2.DateTime as date)
    group by T1.date

update TargetTable 
    set TargetField1 = CountF1
    from #Temp inner join TargetTable 
    on TargetDate = TargetTable.Date
```

Comment: Use a cte instead of a temporary table. That should be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you Zohar.  I replaced the temp table structure with a CTE and experienced a slight improvement.  After running CHECKPOINT and DROPCLEANBUFFERS for each, my original took 27 seconds, and the CTE took 26 seconds.  I'm going with the CTE solution because it is easier to follow.

Comment: Tip: You should start a new question if you want to pursue performance issues. The _actual execution plan_ is the place to start investigating. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in a question. DDL for the tables and indexes should also be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the recommendation of Zohar Peled. Use a "Common Table Expression" which is often abbreviated as "CTE". A CTE can replace the temporary table in your scenario. You write a CTE by using the WITH keyword, and remember that in many cases you will need to have a semicolon before the WITH keyword (or at the end of the previous statement, if you prefer). The solution then looks like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT T1.date AS TargetDate, Count(*) AS CountF1
    FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2
    ON T1.date = Cast(T2.DateTime AS DATE)
    GROUP BY T1.date
)
UPDATE TargetTable
    SET TargetField1 = CTE.CountF1
    FROM CTE INNER JOIN TargetTable
    ON CTE.TargetDate = TargetTable.Date;
```

Here is more information on Common Table Expressions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql

After having done this, then another thing you might benefit from is to add a new column to table T2, with the datatype DATE. This new column could have the value of Cast(T2.DateTime AS DATE). It might even be a (persisted) computed column. Then add an index on that new column. If you then join on the new column (instead of joining on the expression Cast(...) ) it might run faster depending on the distribution of the data. The only way to tell if it runs faster is to try it out.

Comment: I will give this a try.  Thank you.

Comment: [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/68798)

Comment: It took quite some time to modify the T2 tables and repopulate them, but adding a "date" field as a persistent calculated field was definitely worth it.  Execution time dropped to 11 seconds (from 27) still using temp tables, and down to 7 seconds (from 26) using a CTE.  When I added an index to the new "date" field, execution time dropped to 3 seconds!  That's close to a factor of 10 improvement.  Of course, there's no free lunch - inserting the original data now takes 1.3 times longer, but the system in total is now much fast\rer. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Gil I'm glad you had this great performance improvement. If my answer was of any help to you, you can select it as a solution to your question.